# How can I get projections of an image without using Radon

Tags: matlab

I need radon transform of an image,but I am not permitted to use radon function of MATLAB.So I have to write my own.

I have done some research for that but couldn't find any satisfying example.

- Is there any other way to get projections of an image without
  using radon?
- If not,how can I write my own radon function(at least a little
  clue)

Comment: Can you do Fourier transform ?

Answer (score 1):

The radon transform converts an image in 2D/pseudo-3D to a 1D intensity equivalent. Basically, we calculate the sum of all intensities across one row of pixels for all angles theta.

Original code by Justin K. Romberg (Rice University) on https://www.clear.rice.edu/elec431/projects96/DSP/projections.html

projections.m

```
%%This MATLAB function takes an image matrix and vector of angles and
%%then finds the 1D projection (Radon transform) at each of the angles.
%%It returns a matrix whose columns are the projections at each angle.
%% Written by : Justin K. Romberg

function PR = projections(IMG, THETA)

% pad the image with zeros so we don't lose anything when we rotate.
[iLength, iWidth] = size(IMG);
iDiag = sqrt(iLength^2 + iWidth^2);
LengthPad = ceil(iDiag - iLength) + 2;
WidthPad = ceil(iDiag - iWidth) + 2;
padIMG = zeros(iLength+LengthPad, iWidth+WidthPad);
padIMG(ceil(LengthPad/2):(ceil(LengthPad/2)+iLength-1), ...
    ceil(WidthPad/2):(ceil(WidthPad/2)+iWidth-1)) = IMG;
% loop over the number of angles, rotate 90-theta (because we can easily sum
% if we look at stuff from the top), and then add up.  Don't perform any
% interpolation on the rotating.
n = length(THETA);
PR = zeros(size(padIMG,2), n);
for i = 1:n
   tic
   tmpimg = imrotate(padIMG, 90-THETA(i), 'bilinear', 'crop');
   PR(:,i) = (sum(tmpimg))';
   THETA(i)
   toc
end
```

Comment: Not exactly correct... the full Radon transformation is parameterized by **both** the line segment offset through which the intensities are summed **and the angle** of projection.  It transforms a 2D image `f(x,y)` into another 2D function `R(s, theta)`.  It is indeed possible to do the transform for only one angle but that's not the full transform. I could also just look at one slice of an image, but it's not correct to call that single slice the entire image.  This is important, because further application of the Radon transformation often requires all / multiple angles around a semi-circle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it what you search for but have a look to that :
[Matlab code at the end.](https://www.clear.rice.edu/elec431/projects96/DSP/bpanalysis.html)

Comment: actually it looks like something I am looking for.trying to understand the code now,thank you

Comment: No problem, if you need more help, please try to develop more your problem and feel free to ask.

Comment: I couldn't fully get the idea behind the algorithm which is mentioned the link you gave. The MATLAB code in this page generates a 12x1 matrix for each THETA.But why 12? And also,when I tried to run the back projection code,it gives an error as 'projfilter' is not defined.

Comment: I don't konw sorry, I work with Radon once and I didn't even try to understand it, because wasn't necessary. I'm sure there a way to do this with a toolbox but i don't sorry.

Comment: The page link (and the code at the **end**) is for the **inverse** of the Radon transformation.  The code for the Radon transform is at a link near the beginning called the "projection code".